# Errors Linking ColladaDom

Tags: gcc, boost, linker

I'm trying to build a tool that uses `colladadom`, but I'm getting linker errors. This is my makefile

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -g -t 
OBJECTS = mesher.o oar.o primitive.o assigner.o meshmerizer.o primmesher.o colladifier.o        main.o
LIBS = -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -    lcollada14dom 

default:    all

all: $(OBJECTS)
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o oarcoll $^ $(LIBS)

main.o : src/meshmerizer.h src/primmesher.h src/main.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

colladifier.o : src/colladifier.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

assigner.o : lib/assigner.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

primitive.o : lib/assigner.h src/utils.h src/prim_enum.h src/primitive.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

mesher.o : src/mesher.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

oar.o : src/oar.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

primmesher.o : src/primmesher.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

meshmerizer.o : src/meshmerizer.cpp src/primmesher.h
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

clean:
rm -f oarcoll main.o $(OBJECTS) *~
```

When I compile, I get this result:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in colladifier.o
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in main.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in colladifier.o
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I can compile with no problem if I do it all in one line and do not make .o files and link them later. I.e. this:

```
g++ domTest.cc -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system -lcollada15dom -o domTest
```

works fine on the same machine.

I've run nm on libboost_system.dylib and the symbols that are undefined appear in the dump.

There are multiple other threads similar to this, I've seen them and tried the solutions, but it still does not work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the libs? Like putting "-lcollada14dom" before the Boost libraries?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried this, putting the libraries in dependency order, (libcollada->boost_filesystem->boost_system), and that still does not do the trick.

Comment: I figured it out, for anyone who has the same problem. Apparently, you need to add your colladadom includes after any STL include. If your colladadom includes are first, you get a linker error for some reason.